# SQL : errors while giving WHERE clause on counting columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new to the PHP. I have a table with the 2 columns `Car` and `Age`, with repeating car names. I am looking to count the `Car` column which have same age and showing with new column called Count.

From HTML I parsed the Age column as

`$userinput = $_POST['Age'];`

I just want to retrieve the the Age column using $userinput from table and count number of **same** cars corresponding to same age.

I tried to code like this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *,`Age`,COUNT(Age) As Age_count FROM `table` GROUP BY `Car`,`Age` HAVING (COUNT(Age)>=1) ORDER BY `Car` DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

Its doing the job properly as I want, but It is showing entire database as I am using '*' in my SELECT query. I am unable to include '$userinput' to this query that I could get results of Age which user have entered. I am unable to put `WHERE` clause in the query as it shows errors.

Please correct me if I do any mistakes. Thank you.

Regards,
Athul

Comment: You should share error message.

Comment: check [group by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) sintaxis to see how use where

Comment: **STOP** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statements

Comment: as @Jens said, don't use mysql anymore, as it is deprecated and will be **removed** in PHP 7.0

Answer (score 0):

As it was already said consider switching to `mysqli_` as **mysql_** is deprecated.
As for inserting a variable into a query it is as simple as:

```
$userinput = $_POST['Age'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Car) As Age_count FROM `table` WHERE Age = {$userinput}" ) or die(mysql_error());
```

This snippet gives you a number of different types of cars for a given age.